# Is there a way to prevent onEditorAction to go to the next field?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Basically, I am trying to block the user from going to the next field if there's an error on the textview. I had set:

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

Here's where i want to prevent it from going next:

```
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
        {
            if(isError)
            {
               return true;
            }
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the ime option as "actionNext", then I would expect the actionId to onEditorAction to be IME_ACTION_NEXT and not IME_ACTION_DONE. Did you try that? You can also put a breakpoint or a log statement in to verify what actionId the listener is being called with.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT)
    {
        if(isError)
        {
           return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others